# How to round a long decimal place cell in R?

Tags: r, decimal, rounding

I tried rounding off :-

> ```
>   round(9962.3099999999995,2)
>    [1] 9962.3099999999995
> ```

How to round such numbers with long decimal place resolution?

Comment: It Works fine for me. I got 9962.31

Comment: is it related to options() command? Because i don't know what difference do we have...i am still getting the same number

Comment: I cannot replicate this error. Maybe check `options("digits")`. But also note there's a different between rounding a number and formatting it so it prints only with a certain number of digits. If this is for display purposes, maybe use a function like `format()` or `sprintf()`.

Comment: Computers can't represent exact decimals due to floating point precision. Modify your print behavior by setting the `digits` option--- `options(digits = 7)` is the default and works fine in this case---or by coercing to a character string with the number of digits you want using the functions MrFlick recommends.

Comment: i can't limit options because i have GDP data which numbers into billions

Comment: The size of your data is not relevant to the digits option

Comment: To expand slightly on comments by MrFlick and Gregor, this is related to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). I can reproduce this behavior with `options(digits=7);round(pi,2);options(digits=17);round(pi,2)`.

Comment: Abhay Saini, setting `options(digits=...)` does *nothing* to the value of the data, it only affects how it is displayed on the screen. Note that with `options(digits=1);pi;pi*100`, the value of `pi` is not changing, only what is printed on the console. (I suggest running `options(digits=7)`, the default value, after these examples: setting it to "1" is rarely what is needed/wanted the majority of time.)

Comment: okay thanks guys, i realize that this problem is caused by conversion of character to numeric...."34.72" changes to 34.7199999999999999

Comment: That's not really the point... it's not a conversion issue. It's a universal issue with numerics.

Comment: So how do we solve it? Gregor, you do know that digits doesn't solve the question....instead of marking it as duplicate, please avoid the question if you don't know the answer..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521036/how-can-i-round-off-data-to-mark-it-as-interpolated-or-stale-by-suffixing-in-0-0